# the category of “as” here?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions, grammaticality, pronouns

I looked up the word “as” in my dictionary and got three categories of it: prep. conj. and adv.  However, in the following sentence, I think the word “as” possesses the attribute of “noun” or “pronoun”, because it serves as the subject of the relative clause. So how to explain the category of the “as” here?

> Facebook reflects our hunger for social communication, **as** can always be seen in a phone user who comes to a sudden halt on his way staring at his phone.

Comment: Which dictionary did you use?

Comment: @Tashus The dictionary I used is Oxford Advanced Learners’ Dictionary.

Comment: Learners' dictionaries usually provide only an overview of the most common definitions. When you come across a word used in a way that does not fit with the definitions in a learners' dictionary, try looking in a more complete dictionary, such as the Oxford English Dictionary or Merriam-Webster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, "as" can be a [pronoun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as) similar to "that", "which", or "who", as is shown by your example.

Comment: But why all dictionary I used told me three are only three categories of “as” without the characteristic of “noun” or “pronoun”.

Comment: @JuJuPig See my comment under the question.

Comment: thanks, I got it in Merriam-Webster.  Thanks very much.